# Server Explorer has no "Add Table" (SSDT is installed and repaired)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

My problem is the same as in [Visual Studio 2015 SQL Server Data Tools missing "Add Table" option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241617/visual-studio-2015-sql-server-data-tools-missing-add-table-option)

I tried the selected solution but it didn't work. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with that particular database. I was able to add tables to other databases that I made myself. The one I was having trouble with was a sample database from MSDN, but it may have been old and obsolete or I did not have the right permissions to edit the schema.