# Visual Studio 2015 SQL Server Data Tools missing “Add Table” option

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I have added a localdb to my project in visual studio 2015 and I am trying to add tables to it. I could not see an 'Add Table' item on the menu, as the only options I see are 'Refresh' and 'Properties'. According to Microsoft, SSDT comes preloaded with VS2015, but there is no option to add a new table. Am I missing something?

I also tried repairing the VS and rebooting VS but it is not working..

Comment: Possible dublicate of [Visual Studio 2015 SQL Server Data Tools missing “Add Table” option](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31241617/4275342)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct view, also, here is a tutorial for the local db. If you have trouble following it, please let me know which step exactly you are having trouble at.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx

I don't like giving link answers, but there is just too much there for me to simply sum up... If this does work for you, please post which step you were having trouble with before, as it will help future people.

Comment: Sorry this also not working My problem is that after create a database in VS-2015 suppose we have to add tables in database we directly right click on table folder in server explorer and by right clicking we add new table but in my in table folder after right click it shows only refresh and properties option...

Comment: Is it possible that VS does not have permission to write to the new DB?