# Add table to DB in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

[image]

Hi, anyone knows why I can't add a table? I can click on 'add table' but nothing happens.

Comment: 1. What DB instance are you connected to?2. Are there any errors in the Output window?

Comment: To answer my own question, you are connected to a SQL Server Express (.mdf files)

Comment: I have updated my answer with another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of possible causes of this issue and ways to fix it:

1. **corrupted VS installation?**

An older post: ["Missing Add Table Option"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31241617/6483845) suggests a solution to a similar problem:

Go to Control Panel and repair the software.

Do not forget to reboot the machine .

2. **[Common issues with Local Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233817.aspx#Anchor_4)**

In this post you can find a solution to issues like:
*"A message appears, saying that the data file is locked.

...SQL Server Express (.mdf files): SQL Express locks the data file if you try to copy, move, or rename it outside the Visual Studio IDE..."*

3. **other issues?**

If nothing else works, install [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) and use it for DB development tasks instead of VS.

4. **Review [these](https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/adding-tables-with-ssdt/) wonderful instructions by Deborah Kurata:**
   Check to see if the Table designer is docked to the main window, and that it is not floating or docked to another tab raft (say on a second monitor).
   Also, at some point, the window stops accepting keyboard input. You then have to re-dock the window.